# BDD Test for monitoring on anypoint platform

Tags: testng, monitoring, bdd, health-check, anypoint-platform

I'm creating the test for monitoring on anypoint platform. And first I have some endpoint to generate the token and the I would like use this token in header.

```
import * from bat::BDD
import * from bat::Assertions

var context = bat::Mutable::HashMap() // <--- First, the HashMap

var headers = {
  'example': 'test'
}
---
describe `token jwt` in [
  it should "take token" in [
  GET `example: some endpoind to get token` with {
    headers: headers
     
  } assert [
  
    $.response.status mustEqual 200
  
  ] execute [
    context.set('token', $.response.payload[26 to 102]), // <--- Setting token
    log(context.get('token'))
  ]
 
  ],

  it should "token header" in [
    POST `example: endpoint with token in headers` with {
      headers: {
 
      'token': context.get('token'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'

},
      body: 
        {
    "test": "example"

      } 
    } assert [
      $.response.status mustEqual 200, 
       $.request.headers.token mustEqual context.get('token')
    ]
    execute  [
      log(context.get('token'))
    ]
  ]
]
```

Someone could help me how I can use this token in header ? I have this error:

```
 message: "You called the function 'wrappedRequest' with these arguments: \n 
 1: String (\"POST\")\n  2: String (\""example: endpoint with token in headers)\n 
 3: Object ({headers: {"token: \"exampleToken...)\n\n
 But it expects arguments of these types:\n  1: String\n  2: String\n  3: HttpCustomOptions\n",
 
 "location": "\n144|     wrappedRequest(method, stringInterpolation(parts, interpolation map $ as String), configDelegate(null, null))\n
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What does not work, what error are you having or what is that you don't know how to do with your script?

Comment: This script dosen't work. And I got the error. I added to my post. When I use log(context.get('token')) I got my token in the execute part but not in the headers. And I would like have this value token in the header.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to POST or GET is the URL. It looks like you are passing a description instead (`example: endpoint with token in headers`). Also when you have an authorization token usually it is sent in the standard `Authorization` HTTP header.

Example:

```
POST `http://somehost/somepath` with {
      headers: {
         Authorization: context.get('token'),
         ...
      }
      ...
},
```

Comment: Sorry this "example:... etc" it's only example I know that there should be the endpoint. Using Authorization doesn't work. Because normally this endpoint it's working in the postman that in the header there is the key- token and value -token.